# System.TypeInitializationException in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I've been facing one issue with my UWP app: `System.TypeInitializationException`.

This issue crashes my app and the crash analytics reported the following log:

> Hardware Model:      RM-1085_15300
>   OS Version:      Windows 10.0.15254.12
>
> Exception Type:  System.TypeInitializationException
>   Crashed Thread:  2
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   TypeInitialization_Type_NoTypeAvailable

When I run the app on my PC and mobile (Lumia 640) it works fine. It is known to have occurred only on two devices `Lumia 950 XL` and `HP SPECTRE X2 Detachable`.

What can be the cause of this issue? And, How can I fix it?

*There are some questions here(SO) similar to this, but that can't help me.*

Comment: If just according to your crash report, it's hard to locate where the issue is. You would need to do troubleshooting. You could see this issue occurs on  Windows 10.0.15254.12, then, you could debug your code on windows phone or windows emulator which the OS version is 10.0.15254.12.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have those devices to test and debug, but I'll try using the simulator.